# View layout after setvisibility

Tags: android, android-relativelayout

I've got problem with setting visibility to relative layout. I have part of big layout in relativelayout and below that next TextView. But in my code, when           `myRelativeLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);`
is called, TextView which is below that did not appear. I tried several ways to rearange layout, but i need that textview under it. Thanks

My XML:

```
<merge xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/scrollView_liab_ra_flipper_04"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/linearLayout_liab_ra_flipper_04"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/someTextView"
                android:text="Something" />

            <!-- This relative layout should be removable -->
            <RelativeLayout
                android:id="@+id/vg_liab_ra_04_flipper_car_container_visible"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@+id/someTextView" >

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tv_1"
                    style="@style/WhiteFormText"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
                    android:text="@string/licence_plate_counter" >
                </TextView>

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/et_1"
                    style="@style/WhiteFormField"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/tv_1"
                    android:hint="@string/licence_plate_hint" >
                </EditText>
            </RelativeLayout>

            <!-- This textview is not visible if relative layout is gone -->
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tv_liab_ra_04_flipper_mandat"
                style="@style/WhiteFormTextHint"
                android:layout_below="@+id/vg_liab_ra_04_flipper_car_container_visible"
                android:layout_marginBottom="15dp"
                android:text="@string/mandatory_field" >
            </TextView>
        </RelativeLayout>

    </ScrollView>
</merge>
```

Java Code:

```
 private void hideCar() {      

   if (!accident.getParticipant(0)) {
        rlCarContainer.setVisibility(View.GONE);

    } else {
        rlCarContainer.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

    }

}
```

Comment: The only child of your RelativeLayout is the TextView. If you move the TextView out of the RelativeLayout it'll solve your problem, but then I don't get why you'll want to set the visibility of an empty RelativeLayout to "gone".

Comment: To be clear: you are setting `vg_liab_ra_04_flipper_car_container_visible`'s visibility to `GONE` not `linearLayout_liab_ra_flipper_04`? Can you still see TextView `someTextView`?

Comment: @Sam Yes, im setting vg_liab_ra_04_flipper_car_container_visible to GONE. someTextView is still visible, tv_liab_ra_04_flipper_mandat is not

Comment: @eightx2 i added to relative layout textview and edittext, its not empty. I cant put textview out of relativelayout, because scrollview can have only one child

Comment: Try to replace the *linearLayout_liab_ra_flipper_04* `RelativeLayout` with a `LinearLayout` with orientation vertical and see if the problem still exists.

Comment: is it solve? as Luksprog solution is right because you removing the view which is working for like a base for tv_liab_ra_04_flipper_mandat.. so use LinearLayout

Comment: I still don't see why it shouldn't work, please post the relevant java code.

Comment: Unfortunately, linear layout did not solve the problem. I had linear layout at first and it was not working.

Comment: With some minor changes to your XML (removing themes, adding height / width, changing strings), everything works for me... The problem appears to be somewhere else in your code.

Comment: ok  user1478296 can you try with making visibility invisible (not gone) to test ....

Comment: Thanks to everyone, there was nothing wrong with xml or that code. (code is not mine, i am just making little changes). And somewhere else in code that textview was setted to gone

Comment: If you solved the problem, add an answer with what was wrong and mark it as correct.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to do what you want is to use `LinearLayout` instead of your root `RelativeLayout`.. the child views will get realigned after you hide the `RelativeLayout` just the way you want.. if you don't want that, you can use `android:layout_alignWithParentIfMissing` on the `TextView` see [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.html#attr_android%3alayout_alignWithParentIfMissing) the documentation. That won't work exactly how you want but it might help you to solve the problem :).